# Creating a result set of data using data from one table joining on another table containing two key columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a summarised result set joining two tables.

The first table (main and multi row) contains say the following columns:

`trans_id`,
`trans_type_id`

The second table (one row only) contains:

`from_trans_type_id`, 
`to_trans_type_id`

I'm trying to join the two tables so that `from_trans_type_id = trans_type_id` and `to_trans_type_id = trans_type_id` and get the relevant `trans_id` values

I've tried self joining and derived joins to no effect.

The end result is that I'm looking to get a result set that looks something like this:

```
trans_id as from_trans_id, from_trans_type_id, trans_id as to_trans_id, to_trans_type_id
```

data is:

[image: First table]

[image: Second Table]

Comment: Please provide sample data. But, based on your question, I think there are no records which satisfy the condition from_trans_type_id = trans_type_id and to_trans_type_id = trans_type_id. Other than this, I see no other problem with your logic

Comment: I've added some sample data

Answer (score 0):

you can use join with multiple instance of firsttable

```
select b.trans_id as from_trans_id, from_trans_type_id, c.trans_id as to_trans_id, to_trans_type_id 
from secondtable a 
inner join firsttable b on a.from_trans_type_id=b.trans_type_id
inner join firsttable c on a.to_trans_type_id=c.trans_type_id
```